# undefined method `[]=' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I keep getting this undefined error when I try to submit this form with nested attributes, not sure where it's coming from been wrestling with it for quite a while now, I am trying to let users select an option in the council model the submit their choice, I am not sure if I have my associations wired up correctly or if the error is coming from the form. Am a noob to rails. Thanks in advance.

**Error**  **Updated**

```
Properties::BuildController#update
app/controllers/properties/build_controller.rb, line 21

Started PUT "/properties/5/build/council" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-08-18 08:52:07 +0100
Processing by Properties::BuildController#update as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓","authenticity_token"=>"wBWQaxtBioqzGLkhUrstqS+cFD/xvEutXnJ0jWNtSa0=",  "council_id"=>"1", "commit"=>"Save changes", "property_id"=>"5", "id"=>"council"}
  Property Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "properties".* FROM "properties" WHERE "properties"."id" =  ? LIMIT 1  [["id", "5"]]
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 35ms

NoMethodError - undefined method `[]=' for nil:NilClass:
```

**Council View**

```
<h1>Select Council</h1>


<%= form_tag  url_for(:action => 'update', :controller =>   'properties/build'), :method  => 'put' do %>

<%= select_tag :council_id, options_from_collection_for_select(Council.all, :id, :name) %>

    <%= submit_tag  %>
<% end %>
```

**Controller**

```
class Properties::BuildController < ApplicationController
  include Wicked::Wizard

   steps :tenant, :meter, :council, :confirmed 

  def show
    @property = Property.find(params[:property_id])
    @tenants = @property.tenants.new(params[:tenant_id])
    @meter = @property.build_meter
    @council = @property.build_council
    render_wizard
  end

  def edit
    @property = Property.find(params[:property_id])
  end


  def update
    @property = Property.find(params[:property_id])
    params[:property][:status] = step.to_s
    params[:property][:status] = 'active' if step == steps.last
    @property.update_attributes(params[:property])
    render_wizard @property
  end

end
```

**Council.rb**

```
class Council < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :CouncilEmail, :name, :CouncilTel

  belongs_to :property
end
```

**UPDATED** Propery.rb

```
class Property < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible  :name, :address_attributes, :tenants_attributes, :meter_attributes, :council_attributes, :property_id, :status
  belongs_to :user 


  has_one :address, :as => :addressable
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :address, :allow_destroy => true


  has_one :council
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :council, :allow_destroy => true

  has_many :tenants, :inverse_of => :property
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :tenants, :allow_destroy => true, :reject_if     => :all_blank

  has_one :meter
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :meter, :allow_destroy => true


  validates :name,      :presence => :true
  validates :address,   :presence => :true
  validates :tenants,   :presence => true, :if => :active_or_tenants?
  validates :council,   :presence => true, :if => :active_or_council?


  def active?
    status == 'active'
  end

  def active_or_tenants?
    (status || '').include?('tenants') || active?
  end

  def active_or_council?
    (status || '').include?('council') || active?
  end
end
```

Comment: Error backtrace would be helpful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this

```
params[:property]
```

is `nil`. So Ruby complains when doing

```
params[:property][:status] = 'foo'
```

You might want to do something like this:

```
if params[:property]
  params[:property][:status] = 'foo'
end
```

However in your case the issue is because you are using a `form_tag` instead of a `form_for`, therefor `params[:property]` is not defined.

Comment: That's right pierre-louis, tried to make that change, came with the same error, do you think its necessary I have to include status in the form, I am using status for partial validation of a multi-step form following this tutorial [link](http://goo.gl/mKDxey)

Comment: From your tutorial, the `status` variable come from the model. In your case, you'll have to include it in the form or in the model as the tutorial suggest it ;)

Comment: Have included the variable status in the model like in the tutorial I still get the same error. updated the property model in my question.

Comment: Ok check that `params[:property]` is not `nil`. It should be a Hash

Comment: When I remove the params[:status] form seems to work, not sure if its saved properly though, where can i check if its a hash?

Comment: In the controller action, print it using `Rails.logger.debug` and watch your development log files.

Comment: From the logs its not nil 'Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"wBWQaxtBioqzGLkhUrstqS+cFD/xvEutXnJ0jWNtSa0=", "council_id"=>"1", "commit"=>"Save changes", "property_id"=>"6", "id"=>"council"}'

Comment: You logged `params` which is not `nil` in deed, but notice that there is no `property` key, which is why you have your error. The `property` key should come thanks to your form. But since you used a `form_tag` it is not. Maybe you can use a `form_for` instead.

Comment: Ok will try change form to form for

Comment: You was totally right change the form tag to a form for, and everything worked again. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 4):

A better approach to check for nested attributes in ruby hashes nowadays is to use `dig`

Example:

```
params.dig(:property, :status)
```

If the key is not defined nil is returned.

Answer (score 0):

If using a data file, make sure there's not a stray `-` in the `data.yml`. [See this GitHub comment](https://github.com/Shopify/liquid/issues/223#issuecomment-841730223)